# Not understanding why I'm getting error message

Tags: c++

I coded this program and I been looking on it for the last two hours before coming here. I get the error message **Function or variable unsafe consider using strcpy_s** my book says nothing about strcpy_s. Maybe a fresh set of eye's will see what I don't see. here is the code I wrote

```
  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include <iostream>
  #include <iomanip>
  #include <string>


  using namespace std;

  class HotelRoom
  {
   private:
char room_no [3];
char* guest;
int capacity;
int occupancy;
double rate;
 public:
HotelRoom(char room[],int, double = 89.00, char* n_p = 0, int= 0);
~HotelRoom();
void Display_get_number();
void Display_guest();
int get_capacity();
int get_status();
double get_rate();
void change_rate(double);
bool change_status(int);

};  
 HotelRoom::HotelRoom (char room[], int cap, double rt, char*n_p, int occup)
{
strcpy(room_no, room);
guest = new char[strlen(n_p) + 1];
strcpy(guest, n_p);
capacity = cap;
    occupancy = occup;
rate = rt;
cout << " defaut for the following " << room << endl << endl;
cout << " Capacity " << capacity << endl <<  endl;
cout << " rate " << rate << endl <<  endl;
cout << " Room Guest " << guest << endl << endl;
cout << " Occupancy " << occupancy <<  endl << endl;

  }
  HotelRoom::~HotelRoom()
  {
cout << "\nHotelRoom " << room_no <<" terminated. ";
delete [] guest;
  }
  void HotelRoom::Display_get_number()
  {
cout << room_no;
  }
  void HotelRoom::Display_guest()
  {
cout << guest;
  }
  int HotelRoom::get_capacity()
  {
return capacity;
  }
  int HotelRoom::get_status()
  {

return occupancy;
  }
   double HotelRoom::get_rate()
  {
return rate;
  }

   void HotelRoom::change_rate( double amount)
  {
rate += amount;
  }
  bool HotelRoom::change_status(int occupancy)
  {
    if (occupancy <= capacity )
    {
        this-> occupancy = occupancy;
        return true;
    }
    else
       return false;
   }



    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])

 {

cout << setprecision(2)
     << setiosflags(ios::fixed)
     << setiosflags(ios::showpoint);

HotelRoom guest ("134",4,0, "Dennard Beale", 0);


cout << endl;
cout << " *****End of program***** " << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;

 }
```

Comment: That's a warning and the book probably says nothing because `strcpy_s` is non-standard.

Comment: The message also says how to turn off the warning. But really what you should do is use `std::string` instead of `char*`. This is a C++ program, you should write C++ code not C code.

Comment: BTW your code is bugged. `char room_no[3];` but `HotelRoom guest ("134",...`. If you are going to strcpy `"134"` you need **four** characters in your array, remember that C strings have a nul terminator. You see? The warning was correct, it's dangerous to use `strcpy`. You should use `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

[strcpy_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is a version of `strcpy` with security enhancements as described in [Security Enhancements in the CRT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ef0s5kh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

`strcpy` is 'unsafe' because it can cause [Buffer Overflows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). A malicious user can [exploit this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow#Exploitation) to gain control over your program. As such, strcpy_s (read as 'string copy secure') was introduced by Microsoft, rendering `strcpy` deprecated. You should use `strcpy_s` instead of `strcpy` in Visual Studio.

Alternatively, use [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

Answer (score 1):

Hi strcpy in the standard library doesn't check if the buffer to be copied is greater than destination buffer whereas strcpy_s performs this check using the size_t numofElements.
Example

```
char chbuff[10]={0}; //a buffer
strcpy(chbuff,"helloworld!"); //This will probably cause buffer overrun and undefined behaviour  
strcpy_s(chbuff,10,"helloworld!"); //this will give you debug assertion failure in visual studio with error buffer too small
```

Answer (score 0):

> Function or variable unsafe consider using strcpy_s

That's a visual studio specific warning. From MSDN:

> The function strcpy is considered unsafe due to the fact that there is
>   no bounds checking and can lead to buffer overflow.
>
> Consequently, as it suggests in the error description, you can use
>   strcpy_s instead of strcpy:
>
> strcpy_s( char *strDestination, size_t numberOfElements, const char
>   *strSource );

[MSDN forum post on the subject](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c7489eef-b391-4faa-bf77-b824e9e8f7d2/bugfix-program-error-help?forum=vcgeneral)

Answer (score 0):

> Function or variable unsafe consider using strcpy_s

This is a warning from Visual Studio (warning C4996), and you can refer to MSDN for this or Google this warning notice.

The MSDN Link about Compiler Warning (level 3) C4996: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttcz0bys.aspx

As you know, the implementation of strcpy is to copy string from source to dest. And there is a condition that the source is large than dest. And in this situation, the function strcpy cannot report any error about this. This is called " buffer overflow". So in Visual Studio, M$ suggest this function to be deprecated, it suggest you to use strcpy_s to replace the deprecated function strcpy.

Buffer overflow reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow

strcpy_s function explain: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9(v=vs.90).aspx